# Generalizing dimension of vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have to prove that if the dimension of vector spaces V and W is the same then T: V->W is injective if it is surjective.

My idea is as such:

- know that all elements in W have corresponding element in V (surjective)
- Know that all elements in V correspond to some element in W (map)

I want to use that I know that V and W must be over the same field (by homogeneity) and generalize that since the dimension is the same then the number of elements must be the same, thus proving injection.

Is this valid?

Comment: number of elements is $\infty$

Comment: @MathFail Couldn’t I say if dimension is n, then n * size of Field is the number of elements?

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number.

Comment: There are bijections between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. "Same number of elements" just doesn't cut it. You have to use the fact that you have linear transformations.

Comment: How is there a bijection between R and R^2? I thought that it is a requirement for bijection for the dimension to be the same.

Comment: The bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ isn't a linear transformation, so that theorem doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

No, the reasoning is not valid, since the number of elements could be infinite, and it's possible to have a map between infinite sets that is surjective by not injective.

If $V, W$ are finite-dimensional the claim is true, e.g., by the Rank-Nullity Theorem.

But if $V, W$ are not finite dimensional, the claim need not be true. For example, given a field $\Bbb F$ and the $\Bbb F$-vector space $S$ of sequences $x = (x_i)$ of elements of $\Bbb F$, the (linear) left-shift operator $$L: S \to S , \qquad (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) \mapsto (x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots) ,$$ is surjective but not injective.